Why factory class creates more than one django model?
I created factory class "ShopModelFactory" vie factory-boy package which should return django model "Shop", additionally the model's fields feeling up via faker, than I write test via pytest, but
I'm getting this error after running pytest in django project ->
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "shops_shop_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(cd84e095-7d1a-41fc-adb3-7f5db5e07d50) already exists.
========================================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================================
FAILED tests/models/test_shop.py::test_shop_creation - django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "shops_shop_pkey"

BUT my db is empty and additionally I'm deleting all records before
my model
class Shop(TimedBaseModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField("Email", unique=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(
        "Phone Number",
        unique=True,
    )
    shop_name = models.CharField("Shop Name", max_length=50, unique=True)
    shop_url = models.URLField("Shop URL", unique=True)
    logo = models.ImageField("Logo", upload_to="logos/", blank=True, null=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(
        "Banner",
        upload_to="banners/",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    street1 = models.CharField("Street 1", max_length=50)
    street2 = models.CharField("Street 2", max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField("Town / City", max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField("Zip Code", max_length=10)
    country = CountryField("Country", blank_label="(select country)")
    state = models.CharField("State", max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    password = models.CharField("Password")
    confirm_password = models.CharField("Confirm Password")
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="Is the shop visible in the shops catalog",
        default=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Խանութ"
        verbose_name_plural = "Խանութներ"
        app_label = "shops"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.logo:
            instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            logo_path = self.logo.path

            logo = Image.open(logo_path)
            logo_size = os.path.getsize(logo_path)  # in bytes
            thirty_mb = 30 * 1024 * 1024

            while logo_size > thirty_mb:
                logo = logo.convert("RGB")
                logo.save(
                    logo_path,
                    quality=60,
                    optimize=True,
                    format="JPEG",
                )
        return instance

my factory
import factory
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory, ImageField
from api.v1.apps.shops.models.shops import Shop


class ShopModelFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Shop

    
    first_name = factory.Faker('first_name')
    last_name = factory.Faker('last_name')
    email = factory.Faker('email')
    phone = factory.Faker('phone_number')
    shop_name = factory.Faker('company')
    shop_url = factory.Faker('url')
    logo = ImageField(color='blue')
    banner = ImageField(color='red')
    street1 = factory.Faker('street_address')
    street2 = factory.Faker('secondary_address')
    city = factory.Faker('city')
    zip_code = factory.Faker('postcode')
    country = factory.Faker('country_code')
    state = factory.Faker('state')
    password = factory.Faker('password')
    confirm_password = password
    is_visible = factory.Faker('boolean')

my test
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_shop_creation():
    Shop.objects.all().delete()  # even before model creation I'm deleting all records from database
    shop = ShopModelFactory()
    assert Shop.objects.count() == 1
    assert Shop.objects.first() == shop
    assert shop.first_name
    assert shop.last_name
    assert shop.email
    assert shop.phone
    assert shop.shop_name
    assert shop.shop_url
    assert shop.street1
    assert shop.city
    assert shop.zip_code
    assert shop.country
    assert shop.state
    assert shop.password
    assert shop.confirm_password
    assert isinstance(shop.is_visible, bool)

Again pls note that in my test function I'm also deleting all records from database before creating new model with ShopModelFactory. Additionally I can say that I can create records in Admin Panel seamlessly

Remove @pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
don't use transaction=True as you don't need it and it cause unwanted behavior so  the delete operation and the creation will happen at the end as one transaction and that's not something you want to test

ty, but the problem was in models' save() method which creates pair of same instances
